# Alert multiple column using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to `alert fields`. Here is my html

```
<table width="100%" id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td> Nip </td>
        <td> Nama Lengkap </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='ke0'>

        <td> <input class="form-control nipnya" type="text" name="nip[]" /> </td>

        <td> <input class="form-control namanya" type="text" name="namalengkap[]" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='ke1'>

    </tr>
</table>
<div>
    <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-success pull-left">Tambah Baris Baru</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a id="delete_row" class="pull-left btn btn-danger">Hapus Baris</a>
</div>
```

and i have this jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#rmnya").change(function() {
        $('#td11').html($("#rmnya").val());
    });
    var i = 1;
    $("#add_row").click(function() {
        $('#ke' + i).html('<td><input class="form-control nipnya" type="text" name="nip[]" /> </td>' +
            '<td> <input class="form-control namanya" type="text" name="namalengkap[]" />' +
            '</td>');
        $('#example1').append('<tr id="ke' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
        i++;
    });
    $("#delete_row").click(function() {
        if (i > 1) {
            $("#ke" + (i - 1)).html('');
            i--;
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see from my script. There is only one Row `<tr></tr>`. I can alert it if it only one row. But when click `Tambah Baris Baru` there is another row showing up. I can't alert it. Here is my other javascript

```
 $(".nipnya").change(function(){
            $('.nipnya').each(function(i, obj) {
                alert($('.nipnya').val());
            });
     });
```

So, can you tell me how to alert `after onchange` in every field that showing up dynamically.

Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/spc5884w/

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently what you are using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach to element that exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

You need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach, when generating elements dynamically.

*General Syntax*

```
$(staticParentElement).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

*Example*

```
$('table').on('click', ".nipnya", function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fg89ymew/1/)